# Pandas dictionary of set to dataframe keeping values as list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary of sets like this:

```
{'A': {1, 2}, 'B': {1, 2, 3}, 'C': {1}, 'D': {1}}
```

and I would like to convert it to a dataframe of this form:

```
index, Values
A, [1, 2]
B, [1,2,3]
C, [1]
D, [1]
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Series`

```
df = pd.Series(d).map(list).to_frame('values').reset_index()
Out[427]: 
  index     values
0     A     [1, 2]
1     B  [1, 2, 3]
2     C        [1]
3     D        [1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'A': {1, 2}, 'B': {1, 2, 3}, 'C': {1}, 'D': {1}}

df = pd.DataFrame({'index': list(d), 'values': map(list, d.values())})

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  index     values
0     A     [1, 2]
1     B  [1, 2, 3]
2     C        [1]
3     D        [1]
```